# MySQL trigger in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-update, database-trigger

dont understand, why this not work :C

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER 'Reset Pass' BEFORE UPDATE ON authme
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF OLD.`password` <> NEW.`password` THEN
    UPDATE authme SET `idVK` = '' WHERE `username` = NEW.`username`;
  END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Help pls

Comment: Please show any error messages

Comment: Best Never to create names with spaces in them

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Are you getting an error? The wrong behavior?

Comment: Use `ResetPass` or `Reset_Pass`

Comment: Single quotes are used to quote string literals, not names. Use backticks for to quote trigger name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with: the trigger name should not be surrounded with single quotes; you need backticks - or better yet, no quotes.

The deeper problem is that a trigger cannot action the table it fires upon. Your trigger code compiles, but when it runs it gives error:

> Error: ER_CANT_UPDATE_USED_TABLE_IN_SF_OR_TRG: Can't update table 'authme' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

I understand that you want to empty column `idVK` when the password changes. For this, you just need to set its value in pseudo-table `NEW`:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER Reset_Pass BEFORE UPDATE ON authme
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF OLD.`password` <> NEW.`password` THEN
        SET NEW.`idVK` = '';
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5ToLDxxnBXjSWibPbnuaha/0)** - once the above trigger is created:

```
insert into authme(username, password, idVK) values ('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
update authme set password = 'newbar' where username = 'foo';
select * from authme;

| username | password | idVK |
| -------- | -------- | ---- |
| foo      | newbar   |      |
```

Comment: Great! It's work. I'm understand, where's my error. Thank! :)